# PHP - Best practice to loop through only some fields in database

Tags: php, database

I am making a game where multiple rooms can run simultaneously. I have a MySQL table "rooms" to hold info about all the rooms.

The fields in this table includes "id", numerical id of the room, and "user1" through "user6", numerical id's of the users in the room.

On one page, I have to do some stuff with these information for all the rooms, my current code is something like:

```
//query() is just a function which implements mysqli::query with logging,
//  error handling, etc. It uses the same connection on each call so
//  there is no overhead of opening a new connection.
$q = query("SELECT id,some_other_fields,user1,user2,user3,...,user6 FROM rooms");
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    //some stuff here

    foreach(array($r['user1'],$r['user2'],...,$r['user6']) as $user)
        stuff((int)$user);

    //some more stuff
}
```

As you can see, I have to explicitly make an array for the users and loop through it.
Is there a better way to do it?

And I am considering this code:

```
$q = query("SELECT id,some_other_fields FROM rooms");
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    //some stuff here

    foreach(query("SELECT user1,user2,user3,...,user6 FROM rooms WHERE id=".$r['id'])->fetch_assoc() as $user)
        stuff((int)$user);

    //some more stuff
}
```

If the number of rooms would typically be around 10~20, would this be appropriate?

Comment: Ideally, you want to use the least amount of SQL statements possible.  If the only reason for selecting the users is to loop through them, you could use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to pull them in to one variable and then [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them in to an array.

Comment: Are there always exactly six users in a given room?  Like that's the number of players?

Comment: The max number of player is 6 but there are not always exactly 6. A "0" would indicate "no user". (and `stuff` would react to this appropriately)

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of fields before you perform the query, like this

```
$fields = array('user1','user2','user3','user4');

$q = query("SELECT id,some_other_fields, ". implode($fields, ',') ." FROM rooms");
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    //some stuff here

    foreach($fields as $field)
        stuff((int)$r[$field]);

    //some more stuff
}
```

Then you can change your query and your loop while only changing one line of code.